# How to add content such as Buttons , labels to expanded tableView cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableView whose cells expand upon selecting cell.I want to know how do I add content to these expanded cells.

This is how the expansion is done:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
if ([self.expandedCells containsObject:indexPath]) {
    [self.expandedCells removeObject:indexPath];
}else{
    isExpanded=YES;
    [self.expandedCells addObject:indexPath];
    }
    [self.busTableView beginUpdates];
    [self.busTableView endUpdates];
}  

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
   CGFloat kExpandedCellHeight =170;
   CGFloat normalCellHeight = 94;
   if ([self.expandedCells containsObject:indexPath]) {

    return kExpandedCellHeight;
    }else{

    return normalCellHeight;
  }
 }
```

Now how do I insert something now once the cell is expanded.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
ListCell *cell =(ListCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell==nil) {
   NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"ListCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = nibs[0];
}
if (isExpanded) { //tried setting BOOL var in didSelectRow , but it doesn't show the added button

    UIButton *bButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [bButton setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 40, 40)];
    [bButton setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell addSubview:bButton];


}else{
      cell.opName.text = [theArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     }
     return cell;

   } 

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i am going to modify your code plz check this again

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

       [self.busTableView beginUpdates];
if ([self.expandedCells containsObject:indexPath]) {
    [self.expandedCells removeObject:indexPath];
}else{
    [self.expandedCells addObject:indexPath];
    }

    [self.busTableView endUpdates];

    [self.butTableView reloadData];
}
```

Use  ContentView Property of UITableViewCell class

```
[cell.ContentView addSubView:bButton]
```

Here is an examplle

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"identifier"]; 


  if (isExpanded) {
    UIButton *bButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [bButton setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 40, 40)];
    [bButton setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.ContentView addSubView:bButton]


   }
```

Comment: Doesn't work that way.Plus if I set the BOOL var in didSelectRow After scrolling the tableView...the new cells are blank.

Comment: add  [tableView reloadData] in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: How are you settting your isExpanded where it it in the code you posted

Comment: in the else part of didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: my pleasure mensioned not,happy coding @iCodes,thanks to you too